# using struct.pack to pack a numpy.float32 into 4 bytes

Tags: struct, floating-point, pack

Hey all, I'm having a little trouble packing a numpy.float32 using the struct.pack function.

```
f32 = 38.2
struct.pack('f', f32)
```

The hexadecimal representation of 38.2, in 32 bits, is 0x4218CCCD.  however, when I use the python terminal to run the preceding code (after importing the appropriate modules), the output is:

```
'\xcd\xcc\x18B'
```

I don't understand why it's leaving out the \x42 that should be before the B.

I am running 32 bit version of python 2.7 on a 64 bit machine.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got what you wanted.

```
>>> "\x42" == "B"
True
```

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't realize that since \x42 is in the ascii range it would print the ascii character, despite being packed up as a float.

Comment: Python doesn't keep track of how a bytestring is created. It will always print a particular bytestring the same way.

Answer (score 0):

`\x42` corresponds to ASCII `B`.